# how to make keyboard binding for pysimplegui work even if GUI window is in the background ( not the window in the foreground)

Tags: python, user-interface, hotkeys, pysimplegui

Hi I have a question regarding GUIs , currently using pysimplegui , I want to bind a button to a keyboard key , I managed to do it , for example if I press F12 then it does the job of the button 'stop/play' on the GUI , but if the GUI is not the foreground window , keyboard key doesn't work , like for example if I open chrome ( now chrome window is in the foreground ) and use it while the GUI is in the background and I press 'F12' it doesn't do anything , I click on the GUI window (now GUI window is in the foreground ) then press 'F12' then it works , I want to make it so that I can press 'F12' whether I am using the GUI or using any other desktop app like chrome

Answer (score 0):

PySimpleGUI not control and monitor input devices at the backend.
You can try library `pynput`.

Example Code

```py
import threading
from pynput import keyboard
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def check(window):

    global h

    def key_f12():
        window.write_event_value('F12', None)

    def key_a():
        window.write_event_value('a', None)

    def key_esc():
        h.stop()
        window.write_event_value('ESC', None)

    print('Start')
    with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys(
        {
            '<123>' : key_f12,
            '<27>'  : key_esc,
            'a'     : key_a,
        }) as h:
        h.join()
    print('Stop')


layout = [[sg.Multiline("", size=(40, 5), autoscroll=True, key='Message')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

h = None
threading.Thread(target=check, args=(window,), daemon=True).start()

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event in ("F12", "ESC", "a"):
        window['Message'].update(f"Message: {event}\n", append=True)

h.stop()
window.close()
```